# Отдача файла на загрузку с последующей переадресацией на другую страницу

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста реализовать функционал
На сайте есть форма, после отправки формы, скрипт должен:

1. обработать данные
2. отдать документ pdf на загрузку пользователю
3. перенаправить пользователя на страницу с благодарностью

С первым пунктом все отлично, проблема появилась с двумя последними

```
$filename = './handbook.pdf';
header("Content-type: application/x-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($filename);
header( 'Location: ../end.html', true, 301 );
```

Функцию header() можно вызвать если клиенту еще не передавались данные, но передача данных уже была.

Помогите реализовать функционал

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно использовать только PHP, то можно использовать в header() задержку:

```
 header("refresh:3;url=https://google.com/");
```

То есть редирект пройдет не сразу, а с задержкой (3 секунды). До этого можно вывести данные в браузер. Сам header() естественно следует отправлять до любого вывода в браузер.

Comment: Я передаю файл на выгрузку через header(), этот вариант не сработает